# How many caps can you earn with Fortune Finder?

Tags: fallout-4

Level 4 : "You find even more bottle caps in containers, and there is a chance of enemies exploding into a shower of caps when you kill them. " [Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_perks)

I have never tried this perk in the previous Fallouts but with this " Shower caps " looks to be something really fun and rewarding at the same time.So I was wondering how many caps can you earn in a "container" and also how much do you earn when someone explodes into caps ?

Comment: This sounds like it would be very dependant on the container and the enemy as to the exact value.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the first 3 levels haven't found anything on how much it increases number of caps. I know in FO3 and NV you got a 10% chance to find 20-190 caps in containers from the perk. The 4th level on the other hand based on the video I watched gives 10-20 more caps not sure if it changes for different enemy types because the only video on youtube of it right now shows only raiders. Here is the video.